# How to show sort icon when datagrid loads

Tags: gwt, datagrid

I want to show sort icon on one column when datagrid loads but it displays after
user clicks on one of the column. Is there any way to do that.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

I have to guess since you show no code, but it's possible you never told your Datagrid which column to use for sorting upon loading data. You should call

```
myDataGrid.getColumnSortList().push(myColumn);
```